# nginx config file line continuation?

Tags: nginx

I've got an nginx config stanza that looks like:

```
server {
    listen *:80;
    server_name domain1.com domain2.com domain3.com domain4.com .... domainN.com;
    rewrite ^(.*) http://my_canonical_domain.com permanent;
}
```

with lots of different domains.  Is there some way to break this up over multiple lines?  I don't see anything in the nginx config docs which address this.

Comment: I think it's unfortunately not possible. See here:

http://serverfault.com/questions/571579/splitting-long-lines-in-a-nginx-configuration-file

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There is no need to. This works perfectly:

```
server_name domain1
    domain2
    domain3
    ...
    domainN;
```

Also you could use multiple `server_name` directives.

Comment: does not work for regex style though

Comment: Can I put `domain1` on its own line too? That'll look even nicer.

Comment: @ZYinMD, of course. I even sometimes put semicolon on a separate line :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm not allowed to post a comment; otherwise I would have just added a comment to @Alexey Ten's answer in response to @roothan's comment.  Regular expressions also work using this method (at least with nginx/1.16.1):

```
server_name thisdomain.com
    ~^(www\.)thatdomain.com
    ~^(www\.)theotherdomain.com;
```

I had some trouble being careless with copy/paste; just make sure you don't have any semicolons except after the very last name in the directive.