# Break up a long line in a .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, apache-2.4

I am setting a Content-Security-Policy header in my .htaccess file, and it has grown to be an extremely long single line, which is a bother to manage. Is there some way to break up this line into more manageable substrings?

As a trivial example, say I am setting a header like

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "deafult-src http://domainA.com; script-src http://domainB.com"
```

I can (without obvious breaking problems) accomplish my specific case with something like

```
Header append Content-Security-Policy "default-src http://domainA.com;"
Header append Content-Security-Policy "script-src http://domainB.com"
```

but that will insert commas into the string, so I was still curious if there was a better answer that could be applied generally, without adding the additional chars to the response.

What would be ideal is if there were some concatenation character that I could use to break the string into smaller parts, like

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src http://domainA.com;"
\" script-src http://domainB.com"
```

or

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src http://domainA.com;"^
" script-src http://domainB.com"
```

or

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src http://domainA.com;"
+" script-src http://domainB.com"
```

Alternatively, if I could set some sort of variable and just dump their contents to do something like

```
a="default-src http://domainA.com;"
b=" script-src http://domainB.com"
Header set Content-Security-Policy $a$b
```

that would also be much more managable.

There was a [similar topic that came up for nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/571579/splitting-long-lines-in-a-nginx-configuration-file) and the conclusion was just to live with the long lines (they were dealing with a long regex, so the append solution wouldn't have worked); Is that going to be the case for Apache as well?

Comment: Will Holding shift and pressing enter after each of your substrings do the trick?

Comment: @StixO No, this issue relates to how apache parses strings in conf files. Generally (usually HTML) editors will use such a shortcut to differentiate between line breaks (say, <br />) and paragraph breaks (</p>). This will depend on the markup format being parsed, and the editor. Apache conf files are pure text, and as such have no differentiation between a line an paragraph (regardless of modifier, enter produces a single, system-dependent carriage-return character like \n or \r).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following should work:

```
 Header set Content-Security-Policy "default-src http://domainA.com; \
      script-src http://domainB.com"
```

Comment: I tested this and got `Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration`.

Comment: @kasperd you need to run `a2enmod headers`

Comment: @BazzaDP Interesting! I would expect that this would cause the server to send an escaped newline, but it seems like it concats the way I would want, and is imperceptible from the clients perspective.

Comment: Wow, actually, evidently you can escape any whitespace character this way. Confirmed working with \<tab> as well. .htaccess will never have looked so good!

Comment: Huh, even works to break up regex! @BazzaDP, you might want to go drop this answer on that nginx question I mentioned as well, might work there too.

Comment: I applied backslash in a lengthy regular expression pattern in RewriteRule. I worked like a charm but next line auto tab spaces (generated by VS code) must be deleted to get it to work although.

Answer (score 10):

Yes - the backslash works as a **line-continuation**.  This is buried within the Apache 2.4 documentation on  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/configuring.html#page-header

#### Important rules:

1. Whitespace within a line is fine, ie. any number of tabs and spaces;
2. The last character on all lines except the final one *must* be a backslash;<
3. The final line must *not* terminate with a backslash;
4. The Apache comment character (#) *cannot* be used to comment out a line.
5. You can not break the [flags]

If these rules are not obeyed, the server will respond with an Error 500.

Note that when editing `*.conf` files you can use `C:\Apache24\bin>httpd -t` to check your syntax.

Comment: the problem are the flags, and you can't break the flags